# VBA: How to use vbProperCase to capitalize the first letter but keep every other letter intact?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox in a userform which is connected to a column with data in a worksheet which then returns items in a listbox when something is entered in the textbox.
I just want to type right away into the textbox without using Shift+letter at the beginning to capitalize the first letter that's why I use vbProperCase.
The thing is, it does what it does, it capitalize the first letter and keeps every other letter small, I have words however which have capital letters aswell within the text itself, eg. AirCon, PC etc.
So my question is, how can I achieve that only the first letter is capitalized but keeps every other letter intact how it is written in the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StrConv does not have a setting to change only some letters, just all or no caps, or proper as you tried (plus conversions that are not your interest here) ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function)), however it's easy to make it yourself.

For example the following will capitalize the first letter and leave the rest as is, when entered in a worksheet's code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim text As String
    text = Target.Value
    Target.Value = UCase(Left(text, 1)) + Mid(text, 2, Len(text))
End Sub
```

You could use the same principle on form validation or the connected cell depending on the specifics.

Comment: `StrConv` actually does have a proper case option... https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strconv.php

Comment: exactly, and it is not what OP needs, since it changes existing capitalization other than just first letter

Comment: It was mentioned that the control is linked to a cell. When the value of the control is reflected on the cell, the Worksheet_Change event  will be triggered and adjust the text.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my issue. :-) This is the code I used.                                
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim text As String
        text = TextBox1.Value
        TextBox1.Value = UCase(Left(text, 1)) + Mid(text, 2, Len(text))
    End Sub